# How was the figure of $100m for Jonathan Udall’s death arrived at?

Tags: united-states, current-events

[A judge has awarded Jonathan Udall’s parents $100m](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12944797/Judge-approves-78m-cash-settlement-parents-British-tourist-31-killed-new-wife-three-Grand-Canyon-helicopter-crash-2018.html) for his death. How was this figure reached?

Comment: This shows little more than a link to a news site. Have you attempted to look up the docket, court transcripts or judgement?

Answer (score 3):

This was a figure negotiated by the parties and approved by the judge. There is no official record of those negotiations, and little chance that the full details will be made public. The judge did not award anything.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: @TylerDurden "Under the settlement approved in Las Vegas on Friday"